# node js server random crash

Tags: javascript, node.js, cloud9-ide, digital-ocean

I have a node js server runing on digitalocean. The server crashes without any reason I can catch, at random times. This is the error it gives me:

```
bash: line 1: 22671 Killed                  bash -l -c '"node" "--nocrankshaft" "--nolazy" `node --version | grep -vqE "v0\..\." && echo --nodead_code_elimination` "--debug-brk=15454" "/root/server.js"
```

If anyone can put me on the right direction to solve this it will be great.

Comment: How much memory (Memory Limit / RAM) you get on Digital Ocean to run your program?

Comment: 512, i have the most basic droplet.

Comment: Check out system logs, it might be the [Linux OOM Killer](http://linux-mm.org/OOM_Killer) that's killing your process to prevent memory filling up.

Comment: Check the memory usage. It might be happen that it goes beyond the 512 memory. So it might be killed by OS. Samething happens to me when i am using amazon ec2 instance with node.js process, mongodb, nginx and image resizer utilities.  if memory is the issue, try to add swap memroy

Answer (score 0):

Try to do some log, this happens because you have a 500, in order to don't get offline you can use forever or another lib